# Observing NSUserDefaults set value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myObservableVar" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

But i want it to fire every time I call setValue:, even if the value is not changed. Is it possible?

**UPDATE:** I actually used `setObject:`, not `setValue:`.

Comment: It will fire every time when you will call setValue, even if the value will be the same. How much times you setValue (doesn't matter the same as previous or not) it'll call observeValueForKeyPath the same times.

Answer (score 0):

Use setObject:forKey: when you need to work with dictionary keys and values, *and **setValue:forKey:** in the rarer cases where you need to tackle KVO* (**in your case**).